# Order Collection by child child collection

Tags: c#

I have the following objects

```
public class ObjectA{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ObjectB> ObjectBCollection { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectB{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ObjectC> ObjectCCollection { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectC{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public InternalType Type { get; set; }
}

public enum InternalType {
     TypeA,
     TypeB,
     TypeC
}
```

Now i want to order a List of `ObjectA` by the `Dates` in `ObjectC` that are closests to the current date. To make things a little more interesting, I also want it sorted by the `InteralType`. But I want `TypeB` have priority over `TypeA` and `TypeC` comes last.

I was thinking of creating an extra value that presents the integer value of the timespan between the current date and the `Date` property and multiply that by the `Type` property, but I can't figure out how to actually do that.

Comment: It would help if you included an informal list of example items that is unsorted and the supposed sorted result.

Comment: ObjA has one to many mapping to ObjC? How do you decide which date and InternalType to choose from for sorting obj A? Any Examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all if you want specific ordering in Enum you can do this:

```
public enum InternalType : int
{
     TypeA = 2,
     TypeB = 1,
     TypeC = 3
}
```

Next if I understood your question correctly you have:

```
var collection = new List<ObjectA>();
```

which you need to sort by ALL dates in child elements. You can use Linq expressions for this:

```
List<KeyvaluePair<DateTime, ObjectA>> collectionWithDates = collection
    .Select
    (
        objectA => new KeyValuePair<DateTime, ObjectA>
        (
            objectA
                .SelectMany(a => a.ObjectBCollection)
                .SelectMany(b => b.ObjectCCollection)
                .OrderBy(c => c.Date).ThenBy(c => (int)c.Type)
                .Last()
                .Date,
            objectA
        )
    )
    .ToList();
```

To get ordered list of ObjectA you just need to:

```
var orderedCollection = collectionWithDates
    .OrderBy(d => d.Key)
    .Select(d => d.value)
    .ToList();
```

I believe this should work. However I didn't tested it.
Correct me in comments if I misunderstood requirements.

Last thing to add - as far as I know, Linq expressions are not the fastest way to sort collections.

Comment: Thanks! This is a big help. The first SelectMany wasn't needed and caused errors.

Comment: Well, if `collection` is `IEnumerable<ObjectA>` then first SelectMany() is needed. If `collection` is `ObjectA` then not.